# Deleting duplicate records from Mysql Table in Laravel7

Tags: mysql, laravel-7

I have one table name temp

```
id,brand,message,created_atupdated_at
```

and with time it starts getting huge with 100 thousands of records but most of them are duplicate records of field brand

I have written a bellow statement, which works with small number of records but for huge records, its getting stuck.

```
  $sql="
  delete
  from temp using temp,
  temp e1
  where temp.id > e1.id
  and temp.brand = e1.brand
  and temp.message IS NULL 
  ";
  DB::unprepared($sql);
```

what I want to do is
1. remove the duplicate rows with the same brand name but only if the message is null.

Comment: Your query eliminates all  rows that have no Message see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3a36129443bad43ebb88bbc2e18a5367  so there would be **no need** for self joining. I also build my own query to see if i did understand you correctly whicj keeps one without message.

Comment: any update please ?

Comment: what update i would pist my answer, but as you delete all rows without message, there is no need for comlex deletes see link

Answer (score 0):

I did this wahy and its fast and working fine

```
$result = DB::table('temp')
      ->select('id','brand')
      ->where('message', NULL)
      ->get();

$ids=array();
        foreach($result->unique('brand') as $brand){
          $ids[]=$brand->id;
        }


if(count($ids)>0){
          foreach(array_chunk($ids, 500) as $chunk) {
            $sql="
            delete
            from temp where id NOT IN ('".implode("','",$chunk)."')";
            DB::unprepared($sql);
          }
        }
```